# Increasing volume causes left/right channels to be unbalanced

Tags: arch-linux, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, alsa

In Gnome 3, I mapped my volume up to `amixer set Master 1000+`, and down to `amixer set Master 1000-`. This works just fine, as long as I spin the volume roller slowly. [image]

If I am to spin it really quickly, the left and right channel become unbalanced. [image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you ever figured out how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I could not fix this problem myself with amixer and have been using a pulseaudio cli command as a reliable alternative: `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +10%`

Comment: Tip: If you have multiple audio devices, you can use the default one like so: `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +10%`

Answer (score -1):

You should uninstall `pulseaudio`.

#### How?

`sudo pacman -Rs pulseaudio`

#### Why?

If use `alsamixer` or `amixer` with alsa only, the master volume will become mono (have no left and right channel). So if you change master volume, left and right channel will not become unbalanced because master volume has no left and right channel.